# batch file parenthesis error when running within a CI runner

Tags: batch-file, gitlab, yaml

I have the following script for gitlab. When I run my test using: `gitlab-runner exec shell test-unittest` it works fine.

```
test-unittest:
 stage: test
 script:
 - 'echo: testing...'
 - 'dir /s /b RunnerUnitTest.dll | findstr /r bin\\ > tests_list.txt'
 - 'for /f %%f in (tests_list.txt) do vstest.console.exe "%%f"'
```

but when I run it as part of the automated version, i.e. `gitlab-runner run`

I get the following error

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.80
$ echo: testing...

```
testing...
$ dir /s /b RunnerUnitTest.dll | findstr /r bin\\ > tests_list.txt

$ for /f %%f in (tests_list.txt) do vstest.console.exe "%%f"

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 255
```

Any idea what is wrong? it is just the for loop. I've tried using %%f and putting cmd /r in front. My shell is set to 'cmd'.

Comment: Try `%%f` instead of `%f`.  It may be generating a batch file from your configuration.  See `help for`.

Comment: I've tried both. As I said it works, just when it's part of 'gitlab-runner run' it fails on the second line. When ran using 'gitlab-runner exec shell' it works.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! it was %%f. I did try it and it didn't work, then I realised it was using powershell not not cmd in my config file, so I updated it but never re-checked

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I didn't realise my config.toml file was using powershell. So after fixing it, I forgot to retry %%f

What is odd though, is the first command (the dir) didn't fail, but in powershell running that line does fail.